# Como modificar datos de un registro en C?

Tags: c

pues eso, Como puedo modificar datos de un registro, Estaba intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
    gets(search); // nombre del dato que queremos modificar
    fread(&producto,sizeof(_Registro),1,pf);
        while(!feof(pf)){
            if (strcmp(search,producto.nombre)==0){ //aqui obtenemos el dato en el fichero en la posición en la que se encuentra.

                printf("Nombre del Producto %s\n",producto.nombre); //lo imprimimos
                printf("Nuevo Nombre del Producto: ");
                gets(producto.nombre); //pido el nuevo nombre
                fflush(stdin);                  
                fwrite(&producto,sizeof(_Registro),1,pf); // y sobre escribo el fichero
            }
```

pero no lo sobre escribe :/, he buscado como hacerlo de otra forma pero no he conseguido éxito, de ante mano gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```
fread(&producto,sizeof(_Registro),1,pf);
while(!feof(pf)){
```

Si `fread` está fuera del bucle no vas a realizar más que una única lectura, luego lo único que podrá hacer tu programa es comparar ese registro una y otra vez, lo cual huele a bucle infinito.

Por otro lado, una vez que has hecho una lectura el puntero interno del fichero cambia de posición. Si tu idea es sobreescribir el dato tendrás que hechar para atrás dicho puntero. Para hacer esto puedes mirar `ftell`, para conocer la posición dentro del fichero y `fseek` para cambiar la posición del puntero.

Y, para rematar, has de saber que `fflush` únicamente se debería utilizar para procesar buffers de salida y en `fflush(stdin)`, `stdin` es un buffer de entrada. En este caso el resultado es indeterminado, luego no parece buena idea confiar en que esa función te funcione correctamente.