# Insertar en un array de enteros

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C, y tengo este ejercicio que no puedo terminar de resolver:

"Insertar un elemento en un array de enteros, dada la posición de inserción"

¿A alguien se le ocurre en que estoy fallando? ¿Tendría que utilizar un auxiliar para mover elementos cuando intento insertar?

Desde ya, mil gracias!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 5
int main()
{
    int ce=0;
    int vector[TAM];
    int pos;
    int dato_agregar;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++)
    {
    puts("Ingrese el elemento nuevo");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
    ce++;
    }
        puts("Ingrese posicion donde insertar el elemento nuevo");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&pos);
        while(pos>ce) //validar posicion
        {
            puts("Ingrese posicion donde insertar el elemento nuevo");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d",&pos);
        }
        puts("Ingrese el elemento nuevo");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&dato_agregar);

        for(i=0;i<=ce;i++)
        {   int aux;
            if(i==pos)
                vector[i]=dato_agregar;
        }

        for(i=0;i<ce;i++)
        {
            printf("Elemento %d = %d\n",i,vector[i]);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar cuál es el fallo? ¿Y dónde lo detectas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a limpiar un poco el código antes de responder.

Lo primero, **no uses** `fflush` con `stdin`. `fflush` está pensado para ser usado **únicamente** con dispositivos de salida. Que en tu sistema funcione no es garantía de éxito, como así refleja la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).

Por otro lado, la variable `ce` no tiene sentido, ya que siempre va valer `TAM`:

```
int ce=0;
for(i=0;i<TAM;i++) // ce == 0 && i == 0
{
  puts("Ingrese el elemento nuevo");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
  ce++; // ce deja de incrementarse cuando `i==TAM`
}
```

Así que elimina la variable `ce` y sustituye sus apariciones por `TAM`.

Y ahora, fíjate en esta parte de tu código:

```
puts("Ingrese posicion donde insertar el elemento nuevo");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&pos);
while(pos>ce) //validar posicion
{
    puts("Ingrese posicion donde insertar el elemento nuevo");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&pos);
}
```

Ahí estás pidiendo la posición donde insertar el nuevo elemento... ya tienes `pos`, no hace falta que iteres por el vector para ver dónde hay que añadirlo, es decir, lo siguiente sobra:

```
for(i=0;i<=ce;i++)
{   int aux;
    if(i==pos)
        vector[i]=dato_agregar;
}
```

Y en su lugar deberías dejar esto:

```
vector[pos] = dato_agregar;
```

Ahora bien, con esto no estás insertando el valor nuevo sino reemplazando el viejo por uno nuevo. Insertar un valor implica que los valores que están después deben desplazarse para dejar sitio al nuevo valor:

```
for( int i=TAM-1; i>pos; i-- )
{
  vector[i] = vector[i-1];
}

vector[pos] = dato_agregar;
```

Eso sí, como el vector está lleno, el último valor del vector se perderá, ya que no hay sitio para él.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario realizar todo eso, tu lees la posición donde se quiere insertar con esto: `scanf("%d",&pos).`

La posición donde se insertara ya esta almacenada en la variable pos.

Aquí tu lees el número a insertar:

```
puts("Ingrese el elemento nuevo");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&dato_agregar);
```

El dato a agregar se encuentra guardado en dato_agregar.

Lo único que debes hacer para guardar el dato en la posición que se da es lo siguiente.

```
vector[pos]=datos_agregar.
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses `fflush` con `stdin`. [Motivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/7461/463)